# How can I force input to uppercase in an ASP.NET textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, textbox, uppercase

I'm writing an ASP.NET application. I have a textbox on a webform, and I want to force whatever the user types to upper case. I'd like to do this on the front end. You should also note that there is a validation control on this textbox, so I want to make sure the solution doesn't interfere with the ASP.NET validation.

**Clarification:**
It appears that the CSS text transform makes the user input appear in uppercase. However, under the hood, it's still lower case as the validation control fails. You see, my validation control checks to see if a valid state code is entered, however the regular expression I'm using only works with uppercase characters.

Comment: Are you intentionally limiting your regex to only working with uppercase characters? By your wording it sounds like you might not be aware that regex implementations typically support a case-sensitive switch.

Comment: I'm not a regex expert. I know of know way to support both upper and lower case State code comparisions in the regex beside duplicating every state code twice (upper and lower). I thought it would be cleaner just converting the input box to uppercase.

Comment: No worries - I'd recommend using something like the following (C#) instead of modifying the user input though:

Regex re = new Regex("myExpression", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I am setting text-transform as uppercase to set the appearance of the textbox as the user types, and I'm using the onblur event to set the value to uppercase once the textbox loses focus. The validator however isn't happy with the value. Had you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: why not provide a dropdown for statecode instead?

Comment: @RandomUs1r In my opinion, I have never liked the user experience of using a dropdown for state selection. It's much easier to type NY, then find "New York" in a select list.

Comment: @Aheho if you make it NYC select the drop down in any modern browser and type NY, it'll get you NYC.

Comment: That doesn't help if you're displaying the state names in text and "New Jersey" and "New Mexico" come before "New York" in the list.

Comment: use `Style="text-transform: uppercase;"` or  `CssClass="upper"`

Answer (score 58):

Why not use a combination of the CSS and backend? Use:

```
style='text-transform:uppercase'
```

on the TextBox, and in your codebehind use:

```
Textbox.Value.ToUpper();
```

You can also easily change your regex on the validator to use lowercase and uppercase letters. That's probably the easier solution than forcing uppercase on them.

Comment: I'd go with ToUpper().  Why would you want to enforce such restrictions on the end-user?  That's not a friendly UI.  Take whatever the user gives you and make it upper case yourself.

Comment: I would do this too. Messing around in Javascript until you have what you want is much more work, and you require Javascript to be enabled which is simply unnecessary with Rorschach's solution.

Comment: Current property to use with "ToUpper()" method is "Text" instead of "Value", so you must use TextBox.Text.ToUpper();.

Answer (score 25):

Use a CSS style on the text box. Your CSS should be something like this:

```
.uppercase
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="uppercase"></asp:TextBox>;
```

Comment: The REGEX validator will still fail with a purely CSS solution.

Answer (score 10):

```
**I would do like:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>**
```

Answer (score 9):

Okay, after testing, here is a better, cleaner solution.

```
$('#FirstName').bind('keyup', function () {

    // Get the current value of the contents within the text box
    var val = $('#FirstName').val().toUpperCase();

    // Reset the current value to the Upper Case Value
    $('#FirstName').val(val);

});
```

Comment: There is problem with this solution if user completes writing the input and then thinks about editing. If use corrects and retypes a character then the cursor is again set to end of the string as value to textbox is reassinged.

Answer (score 6):

You can intercept the key press events, cancel the lowercase ones, and append their uppercase versions to the input:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("test");

    input.onkeypress = function () {
        // So that things work both on Firefox and Internet Explorer.
        var evt = arguments[0] || event;
        var char = String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode);

        // Is it a lowercase character?
        if (/[a-z]/.test(char)) {
            // Append its uppercase version
            input.value += char.toUpperCase();

            // Cancel the original event
            evt.cancelBubble = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

This works in both Firefox and Internet Explorer. You can see it in action [here](http://jsbin.com/avulo/edit).

Comment: But it doesn't work if the user tries to type in the middle of the text.

Answer (score 4):

```
<!-- Script by hscripts.com -->
<script language=javascript>
    function upper(ustr)
    {
        var str=ustr.value;
        ustr.value=str.toUpperCase();
    }

    function lower(ustr)
    {
        var str=ustr.value;
        ustr.value=str.toLowerCase();
    }
</script>

<form>
    Type Lower-case Letters<textarea name="address" onkeyup="upper(this)"></textarea>
</form>

<form>
    Type Upper-case Letters<textarea name="address" onkeyup="lower(this)"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a simple one inline statement

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocatorName" runat="server"
 style="text-transform:uppercase" CssClass="textbox"  
 TabIndex="1">
</asp:TextBox>
```

If you don't want to use css classes you can just use inline style statement.(This one just visibly make uppercase) :)

On Server side use

```
string UCstring = txtName.Text.ToUpper();
```

Comment: This answer has been supplied and the reason why it's not sufficient is explained in the question.

Comment: It's fine. Somebody else can benefit with this. Although I don't think it should be accepted.

Comment: text-transform only changes the appearance, it doesn't force the underlying value to uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

**text-transform**  
`CSS property specifies how to capitalize an element's text. It can be used to make text appear in all-uppercase or all-lowercase`

**CssClass**

WebControl.CssClass Property

you can learn more about it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx

---

**use** `Style="text-transform: uppercase;"` or `CssClass="upper"`

Comment: Where? How does it help? Any reference?

Comment: You probably wouldn’t have posted this as an answer if it didn’t work for you. However, where exactly did you place these attributes? How did you learn of `text-transform` or `CssClass`? You could improve your answer by adding information like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
 style='text-transform:uppercase'
```

Comment: text-transform only changes the appearance, it doesn't force the underlying value to uppercase

Answer (score 2):

I just did something similar today.  Here is the modified version:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFormat() {
        var inp = document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_txtInput');
        var x = inp.value;
        inp.value = x.toUpperCase();
    }

    var inp = document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_txtInput');
    inp.onblur = function(evt) {
        setFormat();
    };
</script>
```

Basically, the script attaches an event that fires when the text box loses focus.

Comment: I don't get this. Where did you get the id 'ctl00_MainContent_txtInput' from?

Comment: ASP.NET translates your IDs.  You can figure them out by viewing the source of the page you are working with.  ctl00 is the generic prefix (but it can be different), MainContent just happened to be the name of the Form that the control was placed in.

Comment: Couldn't this potentially break when moving to a newer version of ASP.NET?

Comment: Possibly, but you could always use a unique text box name and a JavaScript framework like jQuery and find the control where the unique name matches a pattern.  I was trying to keep the sample code simple.

Comment: There's a better way to get the client id -> <%= TextBox1.ClientID %>. That would render the correct ID.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using jQuery.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txt").keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode >= 65 & e.keyCode <= 90) {
                val1 = $("#txt").val();
                $("#txt").val(val1 + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You must have the jQuery library in the `/script` folder.

Comment: except for when you're typing in the middle of the text

Answer (score 2):

I have done some analysis about this issue on four popular browser versions.

1. the style tag simple displays the characters in uppercase but, the control value still remains as lowercase
2. the keypress functionality using the char code displayed above is a bit worry some as in firefox chrome and safari it disables the feature to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> into the control.
3. the other issue with using character level to upper case is also not translating the whole string to upper case.
4. the answer I found is to implement this on keyup in conjunction with the style tag.

   ```
   <-- form name="frmTest" -->
   <-- input type="text" size=100 class="ucasetext" name="textBoxUCase" id="textBoxUCase" -->
   <-- /form -->

   window.onload = function() {
       var input = document.frmTest.textBoxUCase;
       input.onkeyup = function() {
           input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
       }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Set the style on the textbox as [text-transform: uppercase](http://devhints.wordpress.com/2006/11/01/css-make-it-all-uppercaselowercase/)?

Comment: Read the clarification in the question itself. That only changes the appearance but not the underlying value in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

CSS could be of help here.

```
style="text-transform: uppercase";"
```

does this help?

Comment: text-transform only changes the appearance, it doesn't force the underlying value to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

Use the text-transform CSS for the front-end and then use the toUpper method on your string server-side before you validate.

Comment: The validation control that's failing runs client-side.

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution that worked for me.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bestupper

You have to get the JavaScript from http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.bestupper.min.js.txt and there you go.

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the "toUpperCase()" function of a string.

So, something along these lines:

```
function makeUpperCase(this)
{
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: That will only change it after, no as they type it.

Comment: You could append this function to the onchange event of the text area and it would update it on the fly, though it would be a little bit slow. CSS is the way to go IMHO.

Comment: @diodeus - if you use TextChange event then it'll occur as they top.  @Tom - does the CSS actually change the underlying ASCI or just how it's displayed?

Comment: @Stephen - That's a really good question! I created a small page to test this out and it appears that CSS only changes the way that it appears _not_ the underlying ASCII.

Comment: @Tom - That's what I thought, as such, it needs to occur via JS rather than CSS in order for the validator to fire correctly

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is a bit late, but I couldn't find a good answer that worked with ASP.NET AJAX, so I fixed the code above:

```
function ToUpper() {
        // So that things work both on FF and IE
        var evt = arguments[0] || event;
        var char = String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode);

        // Is it a lowercase character?
        if (/[a-z]/.test(char)) {
            // convert to uppercase version
            if (evt.which) {
                evt.which = char.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
            }
            else {
                evt.keyCode = char.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Used like so:

```
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddManager" onKeyPress="ToUpper()" runat="server" 
             Width="84px" Font-Names="Courier New"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you. I posted this code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026535/how-to-implement-uppercase-conversion-in-jqgrid . It fail if paste command (Ctrl+V or from context menu) is used. How to make it work with paste command also ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtCityName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Width="200px"
                            Style="text-transform: uppercase;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $().ready(docReady);

     function docReady() {

            $("#myTextbox").focusout(uCaseMe);
     }

     function uCaseMe() {

            var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

            // Reset the current value to the Upper Case Value
            $(this).val(val);
        }
```

This is a reusable approach. Any number of textboxes can be done this way w/o naming them. 
A page wide solution could be achieved by changing the selector in docReady.

My example uses lost focus, the question did not specify as they type. You could trigger on change if thats important in your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet and 1 Number
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicy1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPolicy1"
ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$" ErrorMessage="Password must contain: Minimum 8 characters atleast 1 Alphabet and 1 Number" ForeColor="Red" />

Valid Password Examples: pass1234 OR PaSs1234 OR PASS1234

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicy2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPolicy2"
ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$"
ErrorMessage="Minimum 8 characters atleast 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character" ForeColor="Red" />

Valid Password Examples: pass@123 OR PaSS#123 OR PASS@123

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet and 1 Number
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicy3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPolicy3"
ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$"
ErrorMessage="Password must contain: Minimum 8 characters atleast 1 UpperCase Alphabet, 1 LowerCase Alphabet and 1 Number" ForeColor="Red" />

Valid Password Examples: PaSs1234 OR pASS1234

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicy4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPolicy4"
ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"
ErrorMessage="Password must contain: Minimum 8 characters atleast 1 UpperCase Alphabet, 1 LowerCase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character" ForeColor="Red" />

Valid Password Examples: PaSs@123 OR pAss@123

Minimum 8 and Maximum 10 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicy5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPolicy5"
ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,10}"
ErrorMessage="Password must contain: Minimum 8 and Maximum 10 characters atleast 1 UpperCase Alphabet, 1 LowerCase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character"
ForeColor="Red" />

Valid Password Examples: PaSs@123