# UpperCase display in a Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I need to DISPLAY the text in an asp textbox as upper case, regardless of whether the users caps lock is on or not – is there some property or method I can use?
I am converting the text using the .ToUpper method on submitting to the database anyway, but I have been asked to also DISPLAY it in upper case before that when first being typed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Abhi.

Comment: You are probably better off using CSS for this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202368/how-can-i-force-input-to-uppercase-in-an-asp-net-textbox

Comment: @sunpech that is a slightly different problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use CSS for that

```
  #idOfyourTextbox{
      text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

uppercase that is ;)

Comment: if he uses server control it is better to create class in css :)

Comment: no it is not: css inside the server control creates inline css, that is bad practice ;) CSS shoul always be in a stylesheet, referenced by class, Id or elementname in the HTML.