# Zend_Form: Uppercase in textfield

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, textfield, uppercase

I want to create a textfield element in Zend Form which always type in uppercase whether CapsLock is On or Off.

Thanks

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202368/how-can-i-force-input-to-uppercase-in-an-asp-net-textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend_Form` is a serverside representation of a Standard HTML form. Standard HTML Form have no built-in facility to force uppercase in the client. This would have to be enforced through the use of JavaScript. You have several options:

1. add some JavaScript code on the page that has the form and force uppercase from the clientside
2. add a `Zend_Filter_StringToUpper` filter to the element to make all input uppercase when data is passed to the form on the serverside
3. use a `Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_TextBox` with `setUppercase` set to true

Answer (score 2):

That will have to be client side scripted, if you use Zend_Dojo_Form you can use `setUppercase($flag)` or pop you favorite bit of Javascript in.
You can use Zend_Validate to check server side once it has been submitted.

[ZF validation docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html)