# how to implement uppercase conversion in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, uppercase

Producr codes can contain only uppercase charcters. If lowercase characters are enterd, jqgrid does not convert them to upper case, there is not such option.
How to force uppercase conversion of entered characters in jqgrid in inline and form edit modes for text fields ?

**Update**

I found code in [How can I force input to uppercase in an ASP.NET textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202368/how-can-i-force-input-to-uppercase-in-an-asp-net-textbox)  last answer . This code changes entered character in uppercase in keypress. Is it reasonable to use this by adding keyprees event handler to jqgrid editing controls?

```
function ToUpper() { 
        // So that things work both on FF and IE 
        var evt = arguments[0] || event; 
        var char = String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode); 

        // Is it a lowercase character? 
        if (/[a-z]/.test(char)) { 
            // convert to uppercase version 
            if (evt.which) { 
                evt.which = char.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0); 
            } 
            else { 
                evt.keyCode = char.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0); 
            } 
        } 

        return true; 
    }
```

Used like so:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddManager" onKeyPress="ToUpper()" runat="server"  
         Width="84px" Font-Names="Courier New"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I want regular expression validation in add form of JQgrid. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can use CSS style `text-transform: uppercase` to *display* the data typed by the user in uppercase:

```
editoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { $(el).css('text-transform', 'uppercase'); }}
```

The setting will not change the data itself. So you have to make the corresponding modification additionally. In case of form editing you can use `beforeSubmit`. For example, let us you have column `'name'` which you need to hold uppercase. Then you first add the setting of `text-transform: uppercase` in `dataInit` (see above) and add

```
beforeSubmit: function (postData) {
    postData.name = postData.name.toUpperCase();
    return [true, ''];
}
```

In case of inline editing there are no `beforeSubmit` callback function. so you can use `serializeRowData` if you have remote data:

```
serializeRowData: function (postData) {
    postData.name = postData.name.toUpperCase();
    return postData;
}
```

In case of usage `editurl: 'clientArray'` you can fix the data in `aftersavefunc` parameter of `editRow` and `saveRow`:

```
aftersavefunc: function (rowid) {
    var $grid = $(this),
        newName = $grid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, 'name');
    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", rowid, 'name', newName.toUpperCase());
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingUpercase.htm).

Comment: Thank you. I expected that there was a way to add keydown event handler for input element in all edit modes and convert lowercase to upper in this event. User can set uppercase option at runtime. Your answer requires to generate editoptions,beforeSubmit,serializeRowData code at runtime. Please confirm that using keydown to convert is not reasonable, so I can try your answer. Or maybe to implement conversion in server instead.

Comment: @Andrus: I can't full follow you. What you mean with "set uppercase option at runtime" and "generate ... code at runtime". If you has an option (or a variable) which the user can set at runtime you can test the option (the variable) in the code of `dataInit`, `beforeSubmit` or `serializeRowData` and activate or not activate the uppercase conversion. What is the problem. you other question "Please confirm that using keydown to convert is not reasonable" I can't understand at all. I can't grantee that you can't find an implementation with `keydown` only.

Comment: I updated question about using keypress. Is this reasonable. Use can set uppercase option for column definition in database. Application code should examine this value and generate appropirate jqgrid definition at runtime. This involves generating coded in 3 different places while using keypress required adding only keypress event handler. Not sure that keypress handler works if uses pastes text using ctrl+V command but maybe paste command can also handled in input element some event

Comment: @Andrus: Do you tested the code which you posted? In my tests in pure JavaScript environment **it doesn't work**. I posted you a way to solve the problem. If you would post another code which work with any keyboard event it would be interesting for me. I don't know any solution which hold cursor caret and can modify the keyboard events on the fly.

Comment: According to code author in referenced answer it should work. Which testcase you used? Maybe I should ask pure javascript question about that. There are possibilities: using your great answer, trying to put keypress to work, implementing this in C# in server in BeforeSave and BeforeInsert entity methods, creating insert and update triggers in database server. Which is best way?

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202368/how-can-i-force-input-to-uppercase-in-an-asp-net-textbox about 5 answers recommend to use keyUp and in keyup simply convert whole value to uppercase. This does not require modifying the keyboard events so it should work.

Comment: @Andrus: If you read the answers carefully you will find in all questions the code like `input.value += char.toUpperCase();` or `$("#txt").val($("#txt").val().toUpperCase());` So the `value` of `<input>` control will be reset. This changes the caret position of the `<input>` control, which is not needed in my solution. Just changing of event properties of any keyboard event seems be not enough to modify the key on the fly so that the modified value will be placed in the `<input>` control. If you know a way - post it me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed the caret change issue. Is it reasonable to place value reset code to blur event? In this case caret position reset is acceptable since some other control receives focus.

Comment: @Andrus: If one uses `editoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { $(el).css('text-transform', 'uppercase'); }}` which I suggested the user don't see that the data in the `<input>` control are saved not in uppercase. So it is important to convert data to uppercase only at the end of editing (on submitting) of data. So converting of the data an every `blur` event is not really needed. You should in any way choose the way which is the best on your environment.

Comment: I want regular expression validation in add form of JQgrid. How can I do that ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: You can use custom rules (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example)). Some time before I suggested to introduce regex validation (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/new-editrule-regex/#p22277)), but Tony thought that everyone who knows how to use RegEx are able to use existing custom validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $("div").text("lower case.");
          var UCASE =  $("div").text($("div").text().toUpperCase());
          alert(UCASE);
    });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   var strVal = 'lowerCase!!' ;  
   alert(strVal.toUpperCase()); 
});
```

Comment: thank you. I asked about converting entered or pasted characters to uppercase. I updated question and provided sample code which according to Oleg does not work. How to make this to work or any other idea?

Comment: I want regular expression validation in add form of JQgrid. How can I do that ?