# how to control or change all the text to upper case

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a few forms for my company to use. I consult and insert data into the database, but for standard issues I want to transform the text I enter to uppercase, How I do that?

Example of one of my forms:

I want the text fields I enter in automatically transformed to uppercase, or the data that I enter into my database already transformed to uppercase (in the case that the user doesn't enter it that way).

---

EDIT:

I try

```
$("tbCiudad").change(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

or

```
$("tbCiudad").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

and nothing happens to that field. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer this [How can I force input to uppercase in an ASP.NET textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/202545/500725)

Comment: there is no such element in html: `tbCiudad`. you should use `input[type=text]` for any text input or a more specific selector like a class or ID

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
  $(this).val( $(this).val().toUpperCase() );
});
```

Comment: this do something if i entered numbers? or if alredy enter the text in uppercase?

Comment: i try it but doesn't happen anything

Comment: that's weird. it should work just fine, unless you have some other javascript errors on your page. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpF7C/) an live example of this

Comment: works perfectly fine man, thanks, i change something before, and i shouldn't change it

Comment: To avoid the bad refresh effect of change the value to upper case, can use CSS (text-transform:uppercase). And to allow use selection and other special keys correctly, can put the following code:     $("input[type=text]").keyup(function(e){
        if (e.which >= 65) {
          $(this).val( $(this).val().toUpperCase() );
        }
    });  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hzhh6/25/)

Comment: This only works right if the cursor is at the end of the text.  If you try to insert something, it forces the character to the end.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an event handler with javascript (or jquery if you want) to `keypress` or `blur` events of those textboxes and then apply what Jay Blanchard suggested. Something like this:

```
$("input[type='text']").bind("blur", null, function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using plain old JavaScript use `toUpperCase()`

Comment: $("#codigoCliente").toUpperCase() , something like this?

Comment: if i entered numbers change something?, how i control the text i entered? if isn't uppercase transform it, and if is uppercase text doesn't do anything

Comment: numbers won't be affected, if it's already uppercase, it'll still run the transformation, but nothing will actually be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javacsript method `toUpperCase()` for this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to save it or only show it in UPPERCASE?

If you need only to show, you can you CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
input {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
</style>
```

If you want to save it in uppercase, the server-side is the best way to do it. I suggest creating a custom ModelBinder that would call [String.ToUpper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on every string property.

You can also mix both of this strategies.

Comment: This doesnt Store in Uppercase

Comment: That's why I said `If you need only to show, you can you CSS`

Answer (score 1):

Use this Function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#text_field_id").keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript toUpperCase method.

I am also sure there is a function in ASP to do that such as strtoupper in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Just apply CSS class to all required fields:-

```
.uppercase
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Refer **[CSS text-transform Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)**