# I want to enable caps lock from code behind and lock it till i want

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a form and want user to only enter capital letters in fields.I have already given regular expression validator for this .But to make life easy for user i want to enable caps lock on from back end and also want to have it on till i desire.I searched but couldn't get nowhere.I could only manage to know the state of caps lock alone.Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible from the browser. In fact if it were I'd be a little scared.

Comment: Why not just convert each character they enter to uppercase?

Comment: Controlling the users keyboard is not allowed, and not what you should be focusing on. If you have a field that should be caps only, why not just go case insensitive?

Comment: I think this may be an **answer** to your question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202368/how-can-i-force-input-to-uppercase-in-an-asp-net-textbox]

Comment: In addition to the excellent points already made here - what if the user holds `shift` whilst typing with this "forced caps lock on" mode? - you'd still get lower case input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot enable Caps Lock from a webpage.

What you will need to do is use a Java Script function to upper case the letters as the user types them in.

You can find details [here](http://www.liewcf.com/javascript-convert-characters-to-uppercase-when-typing-92/).

---

I lifted the example into my answer:

```
<script>
 function uppercase() {
     key = window.event.keyCode;
     if ((key > 0x60) && (key < 0x7B))
         window.event.keyCode = key-0x20;
 }
</script>

<input type="text" onKeypress="uppercase();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To make life easy for user you should convert all the characters entered by used to UpperCase.
If you force the user to keep CAPS lock on then for other work of user it will be always on; and that's dangerous.

To convert letters to upper case, you can make text box style:

```
style="text-transform:uppercase;
```

Or

get help from this question... 
[How can I force input to uppercase in an ASP.NET textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202368/how-can-i-force-input-to-uppercase-in-an-asp-net-textbox)